# Jupyterhub - How to share kernels accross users?

Tags: jupyter

I have set up Jupyterhub, and installed anaconda and created a jupyterhub kernel on my user's home directory, in :

```
~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/
```

How can I share this kernel accross all the users in my organisation ?

Of what I understand, jupyterhub spawn a new ipython notebook for each user, each notebook being on the user's home directory.

Should I really copy-paste the kernels into each of my team member in their home directory ? 
Or can we have a central point of declaration for the kernels. If so, how to do it ?

PS : We have an ldap server for login.

Answer (score 3):

In the installation of Jupyterhub, it creates a global directory that all users look at. It's typically /usr/local/share/jupyter, but to double check that you can run the command `jupyter --paths` and it will print all of the paths it uses. You'll want the data one.

There's should be a 'kernels' dir. If there's not then make one. I can't remember off the top of my head, but `jupyter kernelspec install /path/to/kernel/source` might create the directory for you. Regardless, in the kernels directory of your global jupyter directory, there should be a directory for each kernel you want to install, and within that, the .json file of the kernel. Hope this helps!